# I am getting error ORA-01001 Invalid cursor while i am writting cursor show even number of records

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT
        first_name,
        salary
    FROM
        employees;

    v_ename  VARCHAR2(20);
    v_sal    NUMBER;
BEGIN
    OPEN c1;
    LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO
            v_ename,
            v_sal;
        IF MOD(c1%rowcount, 2) = 0 THEN
            dbms_output.put_line(v_ename
                                 || ' '
                                 || v_sal);
        END IF;

        CLOSE c1;
    END LOOP;

END;
```

I get this error:

> ORA-01001: invalid cursor
> ORA-06512: at line 14
> 01001. 00000 -  "invalid cursor"

Comment: You should desribe your problem. This is only code.

Comment: After executing code i am getting error  -->ORA-01001: invalid cursor
ORA-06512: at line 14
01001. 00000 -  "invalid cursor"

Answer (score 4):

Of course you do. Close the cursor **out** of the loop, not within it because after the first loop iteration you close it, while the next iteration's `FETCH` doesn't have `c1` opened any more and Oracle raises an error.

```
  -- CLOSE c1;     -- not here ...
END LOOP;

CLOSE c1;          -- ... but here.
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot `Exit WHEN` and you should close your cursor outside the loop:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT
        first_name,
        salary
    FROM
        employees;

    v_ename  VARCHAR2(20);
    v_sal    NUMBER;
BEGIN
    OPEN c1;
    LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO
            v_ename,
            v_sal;
        exit when c1%NOTFOUND;
        IF MOD(c1%rowcount, 2) = 0 THEN
            dbms_output.put_line(v_ename
                                 || ' '
                                 || v_sal);
        END IF;

     
      END LOOP;
   CLOSE c1;
END;
```